# PCA in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, pca

When applying the PCA technique on a training set, we find a coefficient matrix A, which is the principal component. So when we in training stage we find this principals and project it on the data. my question is  does we apply the same principals or we find a new  principals for the data in testing stage? 
 I think in an answer like this : if we use it for dimensionality reduction, we have to find new principals. but if we use it for feature extraction (like feature extraction for EEG data ) we have to use the old(which is for the data in training stage) how much my thinking is true? 
 BS: I'm not ask and answer the question in the same time, but to tell what I think , to show the points of misunderstanding,  and take the opinion from experts

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "new principals" and "old principals"? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I believe the question is: do you compute principal component vectors on the training set, and then *use them* with the testing set (or new observations in a real application) *or* do you take your testing set / new observations and *re-compute* principal component vectors.

Comment: The answer, for both dimensionality reduction and for feature extraction, is that you never re-compute a new set of basis vectors on the testing data or new observations. The basis vectors that you "learn" are the model you learn, and you use that model on any newly incoming data (be it test data or real world application data).

Comment: @eigenchris , as Mr.F said ..

Comment: @Mr.F even for "unstable" data like EEG ? You give me an answer, and of course great thanks to you, but could you please convince me, to really understand why we should take only the basis that we "learn" ?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the data is. The problem is overfitting. If you re-train your model for every new data point you receive, then of course the model will perform well for those data, but it will become too overly attached to that specific data, and so when new data are observed, the errors will become more severe.

Comment: This principal is not only for PCA, it applies for any time you train a model (or a representation) for your data. You have to draw a line in the sand and declare at which point you believe the data you have captured are an adequate sample to express the variation of the process that generates the data. Of course it won't be perfect: you don't have an infinite training sample that covers every corner of the data's distribution. But the alternative of always re-training the model on every new point will lead to overfitting errors which can be even worse than underfitting loss of accuracy.

Comment: @Mr.F based on my knowledge, the model is represented by the classification algorithm (i.e neural network, SVM )not in  the feature extraction techniques, the last one used for get the features based on the data itself(except some techniques like Common-Spatial filters)

Comment: @user3840877 That is incorrect. Firstly, you could simply use the result of a PCA projection itself *as* the 'algorithm' (which doesn't have to be classification either, it can be regression or other things). Secondly, any type of transformation of variables (like scaling, denoising, re-centering, etc.) that you apply to the inputs for training must also be applied to the inputs for testing. If you scale the training data by 1/5, you cannot then scale the testing data by 1/6 or it would be a different model. It's the exact same regarding PCA: you can't just switch the basis at your whim.

Comment: @Mr.F thank you so much for your time and effort, you give me a perfect answer ,if you re-post this in answer,  I'm sure that will help other peoples, as it helps  me :)

Comment: @Mr.F, after reading your final comments many times, could one conclude that if we use fourier transform as a feature extraction, then we have to use a bases or model that we learn from training stage? (this is a discussion between me and a friend :) )

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last question. Are you asking this: if you extract a sequence of Fourier coefficients and call that sequence the feature vector of any training sample, then must you use the same Fourier-based inner product (to get the same coefficients) on the testing data? If so, the answer is yes. However you calculate a feature vector as a function of a training sample, that same, exact function must be applied to testing data. The same would be true of wavelets, or any other kind of basis transfer.

Comment: This can actually be quite tricky for using a time-frequency decomposition for a feature vector. Because sometimes the "samples" you observe will not have the same duration (think of doing a Fourier transform of two audio signals where one is 30 seconds long and the other is 35 seconds long). You have to do zero-padding, downsampling, or other tricks to normalize the incoming data onto a comparable time-grid before you can apply these types of feature methods, which usually makes them perform poorly.

Comment: Another example would be to think just of the DC (total energy) coefficient of two equivalent signals of different lengths. Purely by the accident of one signal being longer than the other, that coefficient will be higher, so if you trained a classifier on it, part of the embedded logic of the classifier would be that it detects longer signals, which might not have anything to do with your application logic.

Comment: @Mr.F that's another reason for dividing or segmenting the data into shorter intervals, to make sure that in real-time application, no matter how the  much the data is short,  the system will work. for example, for a  system for speech recognition, we must segment the speech data into short intervals(i.e .5 second) to be sure that each word that the speaker will say, the system will understand it.

Comment: I just want to chime in that I 100% agree with Mr F regarding the fact that you can not do PCA in new data and work from there. His interpretations and explanations are relevant and on point.

Comment: @Mr.F when epoching/segmenting the data, we will have more than one  group of bases, for example, for a class A, Assume  we have 2000 samples,doing a time-based epoching where each 128 samples will group together then doing PCA on each epoch, will give for each epoch it's own bases,which will give ~16  group of bases , So what bases we will take it as a model? or we should doing PCA or calculate the bases before segmentation/epoching ?

Comment: @Learner Yes, the last thing. You should have a training set that embodies all knowledge you are able to have *prior* to testing and/or encountering new in-the-wild data. Find the most explanatory basis for *that* entire set of data, and then re-use it every time you encounter new test or in-the-wild data that needs to be transformed into its associated set of basis coefficients. If it's computationally challenging, you can also do randomized PCA by drawing a smaller data set uniformly from the combined set of all epochs. With a reasonable sample size, randomized PCA is a good approximation.

Comment: @Mr.F  so you advice to do PCA before epoching, if it's not possible just pick randomly a basis for an epoch.

Comment: @Mr.F another question: do we need a basis for each type/class or just one basis for the whole data ?

Comment: If the classes are meaningfully different from each other, like different clusters, this will be apparent if you learn the most informative basis from among the entire data set. Then coefficient vectors will put them naturally into their different clustered areas of the transformed space. The trouble will be whether a projection down into a lower dimension (usually the point of PCA) causes you to lose some discriminative ability by essentially mapping different clusters on top of one another, clobbering them. An alternate approach meant to handle this is ISOMAP.

Comment: On the other hand, what would it accomplish to take data you've already separated and perform PCA locally in that region of feature-space? In that case, you would be implicitly saying that it is not the global feature properties that act to distinguish data, but instead it is the local variation conditioned on being in the part of feature space for that class. I believe methods like Locally Linear Embedding (and ISOMAP too which I mentioned) are meant to handle this, and in general these routines don't require (and in fact don't want) to be re-fitted on each local class.

Answer (score 0):

PCA is one of feature vector transformations. The goal is to reduce dimensionality. It sort of merges correlated features. If you have features like *weight* and *size* and the most of the objects when something is heavy it's also big. It replaces these features with one *weight_and_size*. It reduces noise and also is makes e.q. neural network smaller.

It enables the network to solve a problem in shorter time (be reducing network's size). It also should improve generalization.

So if you trained your network with feature vectors **compressed** with PCA you have to test it with transformed data as well. Simply because it only has as many inputs as compressed feature vector. You also have to use exactly the same transformation. If the network learned that first input is *weight_and_size* you cannot put the the value of e.q. *warm_and_colorful* and expect good results.

Answer (score 0):

Both PCA and PCR are built on the training data and the *transformation* is applied to Test for performance (error) evaluation. With these 2 techniques, you get better results, when not using just a single training dataset, but doing a K-fold Cross Validation where you do a separate PCA for every fold and apply the transformations to the Test sets. Hope it helps!